# Django - queryset in a charfield form

Tags: python, django

I need help please, I'm trying to showing a `select` in my template from a `queryset()` but it's not working properly.

Here's what I got:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
from django import forms
from activos.models import activos
from activos.forms import activosForm
# Create your models here.
class grupos(models.Model):
    nombre_grupo = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    frecuencia = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    offset = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    activos_class = activos()
    activos_query = activos.objects.all()
    res =str(activos_query)
    PORT_CHOICES = (res,res),
    nombre_puerto = models.CharField(max_length=100,choices=PORT_CHOICES)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.nombre_grupo

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre_grupo
```

as you can see I'm calling `usuario` from `activos()` which is in another app from my project, I want to show that result in a `select` in my template
but when doing so I got something like this:

```
-------------
<QuerySet[<activos:alvaro>, <activos:david>,<activos:daniel>]>
```

I want something like this:

```
-----
alvaro
david
daniel
```

I tried to avoid that editing this line `res =str(activos_query[0])` but if I delete every user from my database I ll get `index error`

Is there an efficient way to do that?

Django version: 1.10.4

**EDIT**

**grupos views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from .forms import gruposModelForm
from .models import grupos
from activos.models import activos


def grupos_test(request):
    titulo = "hola"
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        titulo = "bienvenido %s" %(request.user)
    form = gruposModelForm(request.POST or None)
    queryset = grupos.objects.all()
    # query_delete = queryset.delete()
    context = {
    "titulo": titulo,
    "form": form,
    "queryset": queryset,
    "res": res,
    }
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        nombre_grupo = form.cleaned_data.get("nombre_grupo")
        frecuencia = form.cleaned_data.get("frecuencia")
        if not instance.nombre_grupo:
            instance.nombre_grupo = "PERSONA"
        instance.save()
        context = {
            "titulo": "Gracias %s" %(nombre_grupo)
        }
        if not nombre_grupo:
            context = {
                "titulo": "Gracias %s!" %("desconocido"),
                "form": form,
            }

        # form_data = form.cleaned_data
        # abc =  form_data.get("email")
        # abc2 = form_data.get("nombre")
        # obj = Registrado.objects.create(email=abc,nombre=abc2)
    # context = {
    #   "titulo": titulo,
    #   "form": form,
    # }
    return render(request, "forms5.html", context)
```

**html**

```
{{ titulo }}
<hr/>
<br/>
<form method="POST" action="">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Registrame" />
</form>

<p>EXAMPLE</p>
{% for g in queryset %}
  <select>{{ g.usuario }}</select>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just outputting a `QuerySet` (in other words a "list" of model objects). Run a `for` loop in your template to take out each one.

**example**

```
{% for g in grupos %}
  <select>{{ g }}</select>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Show me your view. You might need to use `{% for a in activos %}` instead, depending on the variable you are passing through your view.

Comment: Ok, so it looks like your queryset is named `queryset`. So you can just run `{% for q in queryset %}` in your template, and it should work

Comment: Yes I did it with `<table>` and `<p>` worked, but when I want to do it with `<select>` I got an empty `<select>` I don't know why

Comment: Show me your html

Comment: I just edited my question, but I want it from my `form`, I mean, from my `model`, when I pass my form to my template as `{{ form.as_p}}` it should come with the `select` tag as I want